# How do I increase the font size of contents in Map in Leaflet.js?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am using Leaflet JS for displaying my map.

Following is my code. The map gets displayed. But the size of the city names are not large. Each time I zoom in, the font size is very less. It is not readable.

```
var mymap = L.map('maps1').setView([19.8762, 75.3433], 7);
    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={access_token}', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
        id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
        accessToken: 'your.mapbox.access.token'
}).addTo(mymap);
L.marker([19.8762, 75.3433]).addTo(mymap).bindPopup('Aurangabad');
```

[image]

Comment: You are using the styles API - is that what you want? It looks wrong to me, but I have never used mapbox...

Comment: Yes for styles API

Comment: To me, the size of the labels looks more or less the same as in the example: https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/example-basic.html

Answer (score 11):

If you look at a [single tile](https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11/tiles/16/32751/21792?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw), the native resolution is 512x512, whereas the default `tileSize` in the [tileLayer API](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#tilelayer-tilesize) is 256

Try setting the `tileSize` and `zoomOffset`:

```js
L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={access_token}', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
    id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
    accessToken: 'your.mapbox.access.token',
    tileSize: 512,
    zoomOffset: -1,
}).addTo(mymap);
```

[`zoomOffset`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#tilelayer-zoomoffset) needs to be -1 to account for the larger tiles, so they cover the expected pixel coordinates. See [this issue](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4321) for some discussion about `zoomOffset` and why this needs to be set in addition to `tileSize`

Comment: Can you explain also `zoomOffset: -1` setting?

Comment: added some additional explanation and links

Comment: Hm, this is getting interesting, specially if you throw in also `detectRetina` option. Requires  some logical thinking about the way tiles are fetched from server.

Comment: @TomazicM Does having a non-Retina screen cause any problems after you set `tileSize` and `zoomOffset` like in the solution? No non-Retina machine right now for me to check this out.