# Text size is too small in Mapbox style in R Leaflet map

Tags: r, mapbox, leaflet-r

Does anyone have any experience with mapbox basemaps in R leaflet?

The font is too small on my map. I have tried to change the zoomOffset and tileSize as detailed [in this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/346360/how-do-i-increase-the-font-size-of-contents-in-map-in-leaflet-js), and [in the tileOptions here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/leaflet/versions/2.0.3/topics/tileOptions), but no success.

```
library(leaflet)

leaflet_url <- "https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/williamlai/ckiy242l16cli19mvze8sqlpp/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={access_token}"

# mapbox basemap - font is too small
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles(urlTemplate = leaflet_url,
           tileOptions(tileSize = 512, zoomOffset = -1)) %>%  # the options don't seem to work
  addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852)
```

[image]

Comment: A workaround anyway seems to be to request a 256x256 tile: https://blog.mapbox.com/512-map-tiles-cb5bfd6e72ba